# What does Photosensitive Mode do?

Tags: celeste

In the options menu for Celeste, there’s a setting to enable Photosensitive Mode. I tried enabling it out of curiosity, but I didn’t notice anything change.

What does Photosensitive Mode do?

Comment: Generally such modes reduce flashing lights & flickering. You may not have come across such an effect in the game yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the developer Noel [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/504230/discussions/0/1699416432407623292/):

> It disables screen flashes and other visual effects that may bother people.

Comment: It's nice seeing devs making games more accessible to everyone, this and color blind modes are probably one of the best things to add to help out users.

Comment: I find it amusing that the linked post was created just one hour after I asked my question.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Yes, this mysterious GrammerAngel chap is clearly very kind and courteous, and also probably very handsome and generous. Let's all be his friend.

Comment: Having played further, a good example is the ending of Chapter 5. Several visual effects are toned down or removed altogether.